# biblatex and etex with active equal sign (=)

Tags: biblatex, e-tex

Please why does *etex.sty* fail to load with active `=`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\catcode`\==13
\makeatletter
\bbl@activate{=}
\makeatother
\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\section*{The \texttt{authortitle-icomp} style}

This style combines the features of \texttt{authortitle-ibid} and
\texttt{authortitle-comp}. It will implicitly enable the
\texttt{sortcites} package option at load time. This style is
intended for citations given in footnotes.

\footcite{aristotle:rhetoric,averroes/bland,aristotle:physics,aristotle:poetics}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\globmarks ->\et@xglob 
                       6\marks \mathchardef 
l.240 \let\newmarks=\globmarks
```

Moving

```
\catcode`\=\string=13
\makeatletter
\bbl@activate{=}
\makeatother
```

into the document body works, but I am still interested in why *etex* won't load with active `=`. Beyond *etex*, *biblatex* can't process its options when `=` is active.

Comment: `=` is used in the syntax rules of TeX and in those cases it must have category code 12; so any assignment such as `\let\a=\b` will fail if `=` is active and its replacement text is not a category code 12 `=`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have discovered why `babel` delays activating its shorthand characters when LaTeX is executing `\begin{document}`.

The character `=` is used in the syntax rules of TeX and in those cases it must have category code 12; so any assignment such as `\let\a=\b` will fail if `=` is active. In the specific case TeX finds

```
\let\newmarks=\globmarks
```

but the `=` is active, so what happens is that TeX makes `\newmarks` equivalent to the active `=` and then finds `\globmarks`, so it expands it because it's not part of an assignment where expansion is suppressed. Since the replacement text of `\globmarks` contains `\et@xglob` which is defined only later, the error message is issued. But even if `\et@xglob` had been defined earlier, the reading of `etex.sty` would have already been compromised.

Comment: The moral: Heiko Oberdiek is right with his apparent "paranoia" about securing catcodes within a package.